# How to Set Precision in GNU Plot Graph Range?

Tags: gnuplot

I set the range in my plot like such

```
set yrange[ 0.000 : 0.040 ]
```

and the graph's interval is 0.005 on the y-axis. The y-axis reads like

```
0.04
0.035
0.03
0.025
0.02
0.015
0.01
0.005
0
```

on the side of the graph. This looks totally inconsistent.

How can I get it to display precision to the thousandths for each tic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of the labels can be set with

```
set format x "%.3f"
```

which will generate numbers with always three decimal places.

Comment: It was set format y "%.3f", but thanks a bunch. I've found GNUPLOT questions are very hard to find answers.